# Conditional infinite python loop

Tags: python, loops

Im quite new to python and am struggling with an infinite loop. It seems that this should work given the user input is no however it just kills the program.

```
    start = "no"
    while start.lower() == "no":

        start = input("Are you finished?")
        break
```

Comment: you're instantly breaking the while loop without paying attention to the user input.

Comment: You `break` out of the loop in the body no matter what happens.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`break` unconditionally aborts the `while` loop. Remove it, like this:

```
start = "no"
while start.lower() == "no":
    start = input("Are you finished?")
```

Alternatively, if you want to use `break`, make it conditional:

```
while True:
    start = input("Are you finished?")
    if start.lower() != "no":
        break
```